# NIntegrate fails to converge for oscillating improper double integral with pole

Tags: numerical-integration

How to properly numerically integrate this double integral? I get always errors like `NIntegrate failed to converge...`.

```
NIntegrate[Exp[(I*t-t^2)/(3*t^2+1)+I*t*x]*x/(3*t^2+1),{t,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]},{x,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

I tested different options, like `Exclusions -> (3*t^2 + 1 == 0)`, `Method -> "GlobalAdaptive"`, `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"`, `Method -> "Trapezoidal"`, `WorkingPrecision -> 20`, without success.
If I approach the infinite integration boundaries by $\pm50$, or $\pm 100$, or $\pm200$ I always get the result $-6.28319$ close to $-2\pi$.

MMA 13

Comment: The correct answer is $-2\pi$, never mind what @user64494 says (s/he does not understand this kind of integral). The trick is to use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i t x}x dx = -2\pi i\delta'(t)$ where $\delta'$ is the first derivative of the Dirac $\delta$-function.

Comment: Note that @MariuszIwaniuk switch the order of `x` and `t`.  This is important, as the integral in the other order diverges. (Fubini's theorem does not apply.)  -- oops, Mariusz deleted his comment....

Comment: @Roman: Could you ground your $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i t x}x dx = -2\pi i\delta'(t)$? TIA. The integral in the LHS does not exist in math.

Comment: Only 6 digits correct: ``NIntegrate[
 ComplexExpand[
  Re[Exp[(I*t - t^2)/(3*t^2 + 1) + I*t*x]*
    x/(3*t^2 + 
       1)]], {x, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}, {t, -\[Infinity], \
\[Infinity]}, Method -> "LevinRule", WorkingPrecision -> 20]``

Comment: @user64494 Once again, you need to read and understand Bracewell.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: Could you ground your claim? TIA. Did you read Michael E2's comment?

Comment: @user64494 I can only lead the horse to water but cannot make it drink. If you don't want to see why these integrals are the way they are, feel free to believe whatever you like.

Comment: Despite the warning message, `NIntegrate[Exp[(I*t - t^2)/(3*t^2 + 1) + I*t*x]*x/(3*t^2 + 1), {t, -100, 100}, {x, -100, 100}]` gives `-2 Pi` to 8-digit accuracy. `Method -> "LevinRule"` does not change the answer.

Comment: @Roman: I prefer arguments over emotional words. If you have arguments, please, state those.

Comment: @user64494 Maybe you will believe your friends at MSE. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556567/dirac-delta-symmetry. Take the derivative of both sides of the well accepted equation mentioned there and you will get Roman's equation.

Answer (score 5):

@Granular:  Using Roman and Bill's hints:

$$
\delta(t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i t x}dx
$$
then via Leibniz's rule we have:
$$
\delta'(t)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{i t x} dx
$$
so that we can write the double integral as:

$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+1}\right)xe^{itx}{\rm d}x{\rm d}t
$$
so that
$$
I=-2\pi i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\delta'(t){\rm d}t
$$
and the last integral is easily evaluated analytically by Mathematica:

```
Integrate[
 1/(3 t^2 + 1)
   Exp[(-t^2 + I t)/(3 t^2 + 1)] D[DiracDelta[t], 
   t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]
(* -i *)
```

or $I=-2\pi$

Comment: The double improper integral $$ I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+t}\right)xe^{itx}\,dx\,dt$$ does not exist in traditional math. If the one exists, then both iterated integrals should exist, but this is not true (see my comment to the question). All your formal transformations are built on the sand.

Comment: Can you explain which steps in the analysis above you feel are wrong?  Surely the first statement is correct.  Is the application of Leibniz's rule ok?

Comment: @user64494. Traditional or Non-traditional math it is still math.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk:  If you have arguments, please, state those instead of emotional ungrounded words.

Comment: @user64494 What do you mean by "traditional math"? In the kind of math I use most frequently, we have been using delta functions for about 90 years, and the related Heaviside functions for about 130 years. The fact that you haven't studied it does not make it wrong or even non-traditional. The fact that you are reading this is testimony to its usefulness, since the data links that transmit these words to you depend on engineering that employs this math.

Comment: I'd like report that `Integrate[
 1/(3 t^2 + 1) Exp[(-t^2 + I t)/(3 t^2 + 1)] D[DiracDelta[t + I], 
   t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` produces `0` without any messages in version 13.0.0 on Windows 10. In view of it the quality of the implementation of $\delta$-distribution in Mathematica leaves much to be desired.

Comment: @user64494 Talk about emotional and ungrounded. "The double improper integral does not exist in traditional math" is a perfect example.

Comment: @BillWatts: Did you read my above comment " If the one exists, then both iterated integrals should exist, but this is not true (see my comment to the question). "? Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: [CASE:4897698]  is submitted by me.

Comment: @user64494 What result did you expect? `D[DiracDelta[t + I],t]` is zero for all real `t`, so this seems a perfectly reasonable result.

Comment: @user64494:  I don't understand why you're using D[DiracDelta[t+i],t] for the integral and not D[DiracDelta[t],t].  Can you explain this?

Comment: Given that $\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } f(t) \delta '(t) \, dt=-f'(0)$ for the `f[t]` in this problem, Mathematica gets it right.

Comment: You replace `Integrate[
 1/(3 t^2 + 1) Exp[(-t^2 + I t)/(3 t^2 + t)] D[DiracDelta[t], 
   t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` by `Integrate[
 1/(3 t^2 + 1) Exp[(-t^2 + I t)/(3 t^2 + 1)] D[DiracDelta[t], 
   t], {t, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]` The former results in `(1 + 3 I) E^I`.

Answer (score 3):

The integrals, where $f(x,t)$ is the OP's integrand,
$$\int_{{\Bbb R}^2} f(x,y) \; dA \,, \qquad
 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,t)\;dx\right)\,dt \,,$$
are, strictly speaking, divergent; however, the following seems to converge:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,t)\;dt\right)\,dx \,. \tag{1}$$
So if there is a way to assign a value to the integral, it should be the value in (1). How to assign values to divergent or improper integrals has been extensively discussed for a century but goes back further to rather famous work by Euler and Cauchy on sums and integrals. Those interested in the mathematics are encouraged to ask their questions on math.SE.

Here's the fastest way I found to compute (1), although due to how long things took, my explorations were limited.  I was about to post it when @MariuszIwaniuk posted a comment that seemed similar, which was soon deleted. Nonetheless I waited, thinking an answer might be forthcoming, but soon another similar comment appeared.

```
integrand = Exp[(I t - t^2)/(3*t^2 + 1) + I*t*x]*x/(3*t^2 + 1);
liRe = NIntegrate`LevinIntegrandReduce[
   integrand /. {{x -> x}, {x -> -x}} // Mean // (* symmetrized *)
     Re // ComplexExpand // Simplify             (* real part only *)
   , t];
levinopts = 
  Normal@KeyDrop[liRe@"Rules", "Variables"] /. 
   HoldPattern["DifferentialMatrices" -> {dm_, ___}] :> 
    "DifferentialMatrix" -> dm;
lRe[x0_?NumericQ] := Block[{x = x0},
   NIntegrate[
    ifunc[x, t] (* ignored when full Levin Rule options are given *),
    {t, -Infinity, Infinity},
    Method -> {"LevinRule", Sequence @@ levinopts},
    PrecisionGoal -> 6, MaxRecursion -> 20]
   ];
```

The value (of the real part) of (1) agrees with $2\pi$ to seven digits in this approximation:

```
PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{Clock[Infinity]}; (* running timer *)
2 NIntegrate[
 lRe[x],
 {x, 0, Infinity}, PrecisionGoal -> 4] // AbsoluteTiming
Last[%] + 2 Pi
(*  {77.6966, -6.28319}  *)
(*  3.29801*10^-8        *)
```

Comment: Is this a numerical integration without warning messages or were the warning messages suppressed? Would be nice to give a reference about improper integrals of this type.

Comment: @granularbastard I got no messages (V13.0).

Comment: The code fails if we double the values for both ```PrecisionGoal```. Why is it so instable?

Comment: In fact, you consider a certain iterated improper integral. First, you change the integrand by `integrand /. {{x -> x}, {x -> -x}} // Mean // (* symmetrized *`. As far as I understand it, you calculate the integral by `x` as the principal value. Though you obtain a number close to $-2\pi$, all that is built on the sand. I repeat that the improper double integral under consideration does not exist. (In other case both iterated integrals should exist.)

Comment: @granularbastard The integral is oscillatory, which invites numerical instability. The Levin rule tries to handle that in the $t$ integral. However, the maximum magnitude of the integrand (over $t$) is roughly proportional to $x$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$. As $x$ grows, numerical instability seems to return (that's my guess). Theoretically, it should be handled by increasing `WorkingPrecision`, but the computations take too long for me to verify it.

Comment: -1. It should be noticed that your code is poorly commented, e.g. `levinopts = 
  Normal@KeyDrop[liRe@"Rules", "Variables"] /. 
   HoldPattern["DifferentialMatrices" -> {dm_, ___}] :> 
    "DifferentialMatrix" -> dm;` is not commented at all.

Comment: @user64494 (1) For a given $x$, the $dt$ integral converges, so strictly speaking the approximates the value, not the principal value. Do not let the numerical tricks fool you. They are done for speed and accuracy. (2) I already said the double integral diverges, and I don't understand why it needs repeating. (3) Your last action shows what a jerk you can be.

Comment: @MichaelE2: You wrote " (3) Your last action shows what a jerk you can be." First, this does not make a positive impression about you. Second, `levinopts =    Normal@KeyDrop[liRe@"Rules", "Variables"] /.     HoldPattern["DifferentialMatrices" -> {dm_, ___}] :>      "DifferentialMatrix" -> dm;` is still not commented.