# Integration possible using DiracDelta or in another way?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

Could MMA solve analytically this integral by using a Dirac delta function or in another way?
$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+1}\right)e^{itx}{\rm d}t\tag{1}
$$

```
Integrate[1/(3*t^2+1)*Exp[(-t^2+I*t)/(3*t^2+1)]*Exp[I*t*x],{t,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

Below is a plot of $f(x)$. What is the expression for $f(x)$ after solving the integral? In case it is helpful, the first moments $\mu_n=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^n f(x){\rm d}x$
are $\mu_0=2\pi,\mu_1=-2\pi,\mu_2=18\pi,\mu_3=-86\pi,\mu_4=986\pi,\mu_5=-9282\pi,\mu_6=133322\pi$.

[image]

**Solved related problem using `DiracDelta`**

MMA could solve the similar integral in eq.(2)
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+1}\right)\color{red}{ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x}e^{itx}\color{red}{{\rm d}x}{\rm d}t \tag{2}
$$
where deviations to eq.(1) are colored (see also this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/262369/69288)).
Using the Dirac delta function $\delta(t)$
$$
\delta(t)=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{i t x}{\rm d}x \tag{3}
$$
$$\delta'(t)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xe^{i t x}{\rm d}x \tag{4}
$$
MMA solved instantly:

$$I=-2\pi i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\delta'(t){\rm d}t\\=-2\pi i\left(\left[\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\delta(t)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\left(\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\right)_{t=0}\right)\\=-2\pi i(0-i)=-2\pi \tag{5}$$

```
Integrate[-2*Pi*I /(3*t^2+1)*Exp[(-t^2+I*t)/(3*t^2+1)]*D[DiracDelta[t],t],{t,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
(*-2 Pi*)
```

MMA 13

**Edit note**

In a previous version in an exponent was wrongly written $3t^2+t$ instead of $3t^2+1$.

Comment: What you have is a Fourier integral. `FourierTransform` can sometimes make sense of such things when `Integrate` cannot. Alas, it doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: @granularbastard With your approach you only show that `Integrate[f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]==2Pi`, `f[x]` remains unevaluated.

Comment: Yes, that's the question to find $f(x)$

Comment: @granularbastard With your approach you might calculate the moments `m[n]=Integrate[x^n f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]` of f[x]

Comment: @user64494 Any integral representation of a $\delta -\text{function}$, and there are many, will be reported by Mathematica as divergent because the $\delta -\text{function}$ is infinite at a point.  Until the programmers teach Mathematica those integral forms, it will continue to report them as divergent.  As for $\delta (t)$ being misleading, it is not.  Its meaning is well defined.

Comment: @BillWatts: You wrote " because the $\delta$−function is infinite at a point". The $\delta$-distribution is not a usual function, but a functional which argument is a function belonging to a certain class.

Comment: The plot presented by @granualbastard does not correspond to reality (see [that screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fadg3ffm9r6dp4v/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-01-22%2008.41.28.png?dl=0) and compare the plots near $x=0$). Likely a multiplier was not not taken into account

Comment: @user64494 The Exponential is $-t^2$ in the numerator.

Comment: @BillWatts: Sorry, I copied the code of John Doty. The same issue with $-t^2$ ((see [that screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cd99blgdpdlisdt/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202022-01-22%2009.14.34.png?dl=0))

Comment: And the $\delta-\text{function}$ is still infinite at a point regardless how mathematicians classify it and Mathematica will always integrate them as non convergent.  Check this interesting site for integral representations and series representations of $\delta-\text{function}s$.  https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.17

Comment: @BillWatts: Did you pay your attention to the comment between 1.17.2 and 1.17.5 in it?

Comment: So you think that comment makes all those formulas invalid?  I don't think so.  That would be one self-defeating article.

Comment: @BillWatts: The cited link clearly says that integral representations 1.17.2 and 1.17.8 are not usual improper integrals.

Comment: @user64494 Using the OP's equation matches his plot.  I don't know why you think your plot is different, other than you plot a smaller range.

Comment: @user64494 So what is usual?  The formulas given still apply.

Comment: @BillWatts: (i) You wrote "Using the OP's equation matches his plot." You are right. (ii) You wrote "So what is usual? The formulas given still apply. " No, this is not true and the cited link says about 1.17.8 and 1.17.9 "The inner integral does not converge".

Comment: I don't really believe you are not that ignorant of math, so I think you argue just to cause trouble.  I have had enough.

Comment: @user64494 And the next comment after "does not converge" is "Hence comparison with (1.17.5) shows that (1.17.9) can be interpreted as a generalized integral..." Using that sort of *generalized* integral liberates Fourier analysis from the crippling restrictions you seem to want to place on it. So, the question is, why do you want to cripple Fourier analysis? What harm do you believe it has done to you?

Comment: @BillWatts Correct, the integral representation of the Dirac delta functional as a Fourier Transform of 1 will diverge. This is not because Dirac delta is infinite at the origin (which is, arguably, not a correct statement since it isn't a function). It's because that integral is in fact not convergent. One can define the FT by a limiting process that involves a sequence of convergent integrals. But the form they converge to is not a convergent integral, even if convergence of the sequence to a functional makes sense (which it does).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Whether that one integral is considered to be convergent or not, the formulas presented in that article are still valid which was my point.

Comment: @BillWatts Yes, agreed, those formulas are all fine. My claim should have been explicitly restricted to how Mathematica would handle this, and why (on a good day, at least).

Answer (score 3):

To summarize the discussion:

```
Integrate[1/(3*t^2+1)*Exp[(t^2+I*t)/(3*t^2+1)]*Exp[I*t*x]
{t,-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}]
```

represents a Fourier integral. The `DiracDelta` manipulations are also stated in terms of Fourier integrals. *Mathematica* has special methods that it uses in this domain which can sometimes perform symbolic integrations that are not possible otherwise. However:

```
FourierTransform[-2*Pi*I/(3*t^2 + 1)*Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1)],
 t,x]
```

returns unevaluated in this case, suggesting that those special methods do not suffice.

Comment: I think it is correct to call this the integral representation of a Fourier transform. Except in this case the integral does not exist, even though the FT does. This is different from the situation, often seen in comments to similar MSE threads, where integrals with `DiracDelta` appear. Those do exist, once one clears the hurdle of defining them (which was done over 70 years ago).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau In the corrected version, there is no doubt that the integral exists: the leading term `1/(3*t^2 + 1)` dominates for large `Abs[t]`, and it has no troublesome singularities. It's tame as a numerical integral. But neither `Integrate` nor `FourierTransform` can find a symbolic form. Most likely, none exists.

Comment: Right you are. I guess I was thinking more about something like `1/(3*t+1)` which would not be integrable in the classical sense but would nonetheless have a FT (whether or not computable in closed form).

Answer (score -1):

An approximate answer to the edited question can be derived as follows, expanding `Exp[(-t^2+I*t)/(3*t^2+1)]` into  a series.

```
Total[Table[FourierTransform[1/(3*t^2 + 1)*((-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1))^n/n!,t, x], {n, 0, 20}]];
Plot[Sqrt[2*Pi]*%, {x, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

Edit. `Plot[Sqrt[2*Pi]*%, {x, -8, 8}]` instead of  `Plot[%, {x, -8, 8}]`.

Comment: I'd like to add that the results of `ComplexPlot[
 InverseFourierTransform[
  Total[Table[
    FourierTransform[1/(3*t^2 + 1)*((-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1))^n/n!, t,
      x], {n, 0, 20}]], x, t], {t, -3 - 3*I, 3 + 3*I}]` and `ComplexPlot[
 1/(3*t^2 + 1)*Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1)], {t, -3 - 3*I, 3 + 3*I}]` are almost identical.

Answer (score -4):

As  noticed in @John Doty comment, the integral under consideration is a Fourier transform of $\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+t} $ up to a multiplier.
The necessary condition of its existence (see e.g. [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Fourier_transform)) is the convergence of the integral $$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+t}\right|\,dt.$$
There is a non-integrable singularity of the integrand at $t=-\frac 1 3$ as the Mathematica commands

```
as = Normal[Series[Abs[1/(3 t^2 + 1)*Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3 t^2 + t)]], {t,-1/3, 2}]]
```

> `E^Re[(I t - t^2)/(t + 3 t^2)]/Abs[1 + 3 t^2]`

```
Plot[as, {t, -0.5, 0}]
```

[image]

```
NIntegrate[as, {t, -0.5, 0}]
```

> `3.632573614239987*10^477`NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in t near {t} = {-0.333016}. NIntegrate obtained 3.632573614239987*10^477+0. I and 3.580550483737237`15.954589770191005*^477 for the integral and error estimates.

report. Therefore, the integral under consideration does not exist.

Comment: Can the downvoter motivate  the  vote? What is wrong in my answer?

Comment: `Plot[Abs[-2*Pi*I/(3*t^2 + 1)*Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1)]], {t, -1, 
  1}]` shows no such singularity.

Comment: @JohnDoty: Unfortunately, you take `Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1)]` instead of `Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + t)]`. Hope you feel the difference.

Comment: `1/(3*t^2 + 1)*Exp[(-t^2 + I*t)/(3*t^2 + 1)]` was copied directly from the OP's code above.

Comment: And, integrating that numerically, I reproduce the OP's plot of `f[x]`.

Comment: @JohnDoty: The added in edit code differs from the formula in $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Well, given that this is a *Mathematica* site, I trust the code more than LaTeX that challenges septuagenarian eyes.

Comment: @JohnDoty: The same did josh in the linked threat. Also see lines $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{3 t^2+1} e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+t}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{itx}{\rm d}x{\rm d}t=-2\pi i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\delta'(t){\rm d}t=-2\pi i\left(\left[\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\delta(t)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\left(\frac{1}{3t^2+1}e^{\frac{-t^2+it}{3t^2+1}}\right)_{t=0}\right)=-2\pi i(0-i)=-2\pi$$ in the question.

Comment: @granularbastard: You wrote "The latex expression and MMA code express the same formula. " No, this is not true: compare `Exp[(-t^2+I*t)/(3*t^2+1)]` in the code and $e^\frac{-t^2+i t}{3 t^2+t}$ in $\LaTeX$ ($t$ and `1` in the denominator of the exponent) ,

Comment: @granularbastard To summarize, we're confused as to what the function in question is, and user64494 is chronically and stubbornly confused about Fourier analysis.

Comment: corrected, it must be $3t^2+1$ (was wrongly $3t^2+t$)

Comment: The version of the integral originally posted, with `3t^2+t` as the exponential denominator, does not converge. Also if I am seeing it correctly, the FT it would represent does not exist either. But the FT for the modified integrand should be fine, albeit difficult to compute.